# Python script launched from PyCharm has a different os.environ['PATH'] than my shell

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pycharm

I have an executable in my path called `blat`, which means it works from a terminal opened in any directory. However, when I run `subprocess.call(['blat', 'args', 'go', 'here'])`, I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'blat'`. Alternatively, running `subprocess.call('blat args go here', shell=True)` gives `/bin/sh: 1: blat: not found`. I am certain that `blat` is in my path, and outside of python, running it from the same directory works. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: running `type blat` produces `blat is hashed`.

Comment: How is the Python interpreter started? Have you affirmatively checked that it has the same PATH as your interactive shell? (You can do that by checking `os.environ['PATH']`, or with something like `tr -d '\0' '\n' </proc/12345/environ`, substituting the PID of the Python process for `12345`).

Comment: Alternately -- is `blat` a script? If so, make sure it's not missing its shebang. A shell will sometimes cover for the `#!/bin/bash` / `#!/bin/sh` / whatever line being missing by making an assumption, but when invoking a script with a standard `execve()` call, it's a hard requirement that a shebang be present.

Comment: Alternately -- is `blat` an exported shell function? If so, it'll only work if your shell is `bash`, and `shell=True` runs `/bin/sh` instead.

Comment: ...unfortunately, all I can offer is guesses and speculation at this point, since the question lacks a [mcve].

Comment: It's also possible that the `PATH` could be the same, but that `blat` is a dynamically linked executable, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` differs (so one of its library dependencies can't be found).

Comment: ...assuming your interactive shell is bash, consider running `type blat`, and providing the output in the question -- if there's an alias or shell function changing the way `blat` is invoked, that'll be made clear. (in zsh the `which` command will do this, whereas with bash `which` is an external command which doesn't know about the shell's internal state).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it seems that the python path is different to the system path defined in `.bashrc` (checking with `os.environ['PATH']`). Perhaps this is because I'm running python in a venv? How can I make it use the system path?

Comment: How is the interpreter being started?

Comment: ...okay, `blat is hashed` means it's a regular executable from the PATH (whose location was cached in-memory by the shell), so we don't need to worry about aliases or functions getting in the way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using PyCharm, which I believe just runs `python script.py`.

Comment: Please compare against actual invocation from a shell prompt in a terminal from which you can successfully invoke `blat`.

Comment: You're right: it works by invoking `python script.py` from the shell. I wonder what PyCharm runs under the hood...

Comment: ...it's likely here we might need to look into *how* you lauched PyCharm. Launching GUI apps from your desktop environment's launcher/GUI/whatever isn't necessarily going to ever run an interactive shell (as opposed to a login shell). On some operating systems, this might mean that your `.bash_profile` gets run but your `.bashrc` doesn't.

Comment: If you use the `tr` command I gave you to look at the environment variables that PyCharm itself has set, what does its PATH look like?

Comment: ...so, we might be needing to get into some details here about what your operating system and desktop environment is, how you started PyCharm, which specific shell dotfiles you configure your PATH from, etc.

Comment: ...but that said, I need to get back to the office, so hopefully someone else can pick up where I'm leaving off if you can't afford some delay.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right, I think the best way to solve this is just to avoid PyCharm for this specific task.

Comment: If you modify the path in your .bashrc: This is not read by PyCharm. In that case you can modify .profile (or .bash_profile) instead. See https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc